# Nested namespaced resources, polymorphic associations and paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is this a bug in rails?
I have the following routing:

```
namespace :admin do
 resources :products do
  resources :images
 end
end
```

which creates the following path

```
admin_product_image GET /admin/products/:product_id/images/:id(.:format)  admin/images#show
```

however when I try to return the path via

```
polymorphic_path( [ @imageable, @image ] )
```

It returns an error: undefined method `admin_product_admin_image_path' for #<#:0x007ff8963f0f98>

It seems to be looking for `admin_product_admin_image_path' and not 'admin_product_image_path'

If I debug "polymorphic_routes.rb" and modify this:

```
(proxy || self).send(named_route, *args)
```

which is sending "admin_product_admin_image_path" and generating the error, to rather send:

```
(proxy || self).send("admin_product_image_path", *args)
```

No error is raised.  Is polymorphic_path not working with namespaces?

**Edit**
Can now confirm that polymorphic_url function does not work with namespaces!

**Edit**
By editing **bad idea** polymorphic_routes.rb I managed to hard code a  fix **poor idea**.

```
In def build_named_route_call(records, inflection, options = {}) ....
   ....
   route << model_name_from_record_or_class(record).singular_route_key
   .....
   route << model_name_from_record_or_class(record).route_key
```

To **bad***

```
route << model_name_from_record_or_class(record).singular_route_key.gsub(/admin_/,'').to_s
```

and

```
route << model_name_from_record_or_class(record).route_key.gsub(/admin_/,'').to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in rails.  The edit in my question above is where the fix needs to go ... but my hard coded edit breaks other things in rails - so avoid it.

The only solution at the moment is to not used namespaced, nested resources and polymorphic associations in rails.

Comment: Hey, I just checked on rails `4.0.1` and it seems that it works correct. Can you confirm that? If it doesn't work for you, can you paste your controller and view code?

Comment: @Lucas:  I change my code to not work with namespaces and I don't have a copy of the original code.  I tried to recreate in a new project and did not get the same error, but polymorphic_path( [@product, Admin::Image.new]) returns /admin/images and I would assume it should return /admin/product/1/images?

Comment: As stated here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13365, this is known limitation, I missed that you use models with namespace `Admin::`.